# Pulling IDs from a wall of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm really looking for help getting the ball rolling here.  I have some basic knowledge in pulling parts of a string, but my present problem I'm not exactly sure where to begin.

I'm using an API to pull client data to verify information. This is a small sampling as I will be working with 20,000+ records. The call I'm using to build my data set to test returns data that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "121208",
  "loginToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "businessName": "Business, Inc.",
  "contactPhone": "8005555104",
  "contactLastName": "Davidson",
  "contactEmail": "info@mail.com",
  "contactFirstName": "Dave"
},
{
  "id": "121209",
  "loginToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "businessName": "Business, Inc.",
  "contactPhone": "8005555104",
  "contactLastName": "Davidson",
  "contactEmail": "info@mail.com",
  "contactFirstName": "Dave"
},
{
  "id": "121210",
  "loginToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "businessName": "Business, Inc.",
  "contactPhone": "8005555104",
  "contactLastName": "Davidson",
  "contactEmail": "info@mail.com",
  "contactFirstName": "Dave"
},
{
  "id": "121211",
  "loginToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "businessName": "Business, Inc.",
  "contactPhone": "8005555104",
  "contactLastName": "Davidson",
  "contactEmail": "info@mail.com",
  "contactFirstName": "Dave"
},
```

I'm using excel to pull this data so it comes in a giant mass of text in one cell. My problem is I need to get the ID for each client into its own row from the query and then I'm good to go. It should be noted that some of the clients returned will not have an ID and will report it as:

```
"id": "",
```

Any information to help me learn, I'm not really just looking for the answer, is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the word id and the corresponding id # actually surrounded by `"`?

Comment: Yes, what I've placed into the 'code' section is the actual text that is returned with a JSON query to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into it now; I was going to suggest the same thing as tiger but after seeing it's all in one cell, that changes this a bit. Two seconds.

**Actually, why not copy that cell into a notepad file, erase the cell, and copy the notepad file back into Excel? From there you'd be able to erase the rows that don't hold the "id" value in them, and then it's a simple Right/Left formula to return the ID.

Comment: I'm trying to make it as scalable as possible.  But that is a good idea for the short-term.

Comment: I'm going to have to use this method for the immediate future.

Comment: The notepad, I feel, breaks it completely down to straight text, and from there you can run an Autofilter or a Loop to erase files...i.e. 
Dim LastRowColA As Long
LastRowColA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LastRowColA).Select
Do
If ActiveCell.Value = "delete criteria here" Then Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Loop Until ActiveCell = Range("A1")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the information is in A1, you can use this formula in cell B1 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),FIND(":",A1)+1,99),"""",""))
```

Comment: Is this to just return the number of IDs?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: This returns the ID number. Isn't that what was asked for?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, it is returning the number of IDs and not the ID themselves.  I don't think what I'm trying to do will work exactly the way I want.  The biggest limiting factor is the 30,000 character limit in excel.